# Order Confirmation/Completion email not sent for GUESTs in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce

So I have this issue and i am aware of all the bugs and problems around SMTP and wp_mail in woocommerce wordpress and I've read it all...

I have something different ,emails from my site actually sent(using sandgrid) I am also using PaidMembershipsPro so users with paid membership actually do get email after made an order but users with a free membership or users that not loggedin and paing(PayPal Getaway) per product/order not getting 'Completed Order' email with all the info like it works with paid membership users...

So I didn't found somebody with similar problem ,, the user do filling billing info including his email , and I can see in Woocommerce > Orders  that the orders made by Guest and email is saved and the are in completed state...
So if somebody have Idea how to fix it I would be more than glad to hear..

Answer (score 0):

So in the end after digging a lot I have understood that the problem somewhere in the process of completing the order and that is why email is not sent,, so I wrote this action hook that fixes it...

`function woocommerce_payment_complete( $order_id ) {
     $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
     $order->update_status( 'processing' );
     $order->update_status( 'completed' );
     }
 add_action('woocommerce_api_wc_gateway_paypal','mysite_woocommerce_payment_complete',1 );`